# Type "request" cannot be used to index type 'RequestTypes[KModel][KMethod]'

Tags: typescript

Trying to get type, but sth gone wrong:

```js
public async request<KModel extends keyof RequestTypes, KMethod extends keyof RequestTypes[KModel]>(modelName: KModel, calledMethod: KMethod, methodProperties: RequestTypes[KModel][KMethod]["request"]): Promise<RequestTypes[KModel][KMethod]["response"]> {};

interface RequestTypes {
    InternetDocument: {
        save: {
            request: a965630e_8512_11ec_8ced_005056b2dbe1_Request,
            response: a965630e_8512_11ec_8ced_005056b2dbe1_Response
        }
    }
}
```

TS error:

> Type '"request"' cannot be used to index type 'RequestTypes[KModel][KMethod]'.ts(2536)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why this exactly fixes issue or is there a better way, I think just that typescript cannot be sure that for each Request type there will be reqest and response ?? altough it doesnt make sense, anyways, using conditionals helped.

```
public async request<
  KModel extends keyof RequestTypes,
  KMethod extends keyof RequestTypes[KModel]
>(
  modelName: KModel,
  calledMethod: KMethod,
  methodProperties: "request" extends keyof RequestTypes[KModel][KMethod]
    ? RequestTypes[KModel][KMethod]["request"]
    : never
): Promise<
  "response" extends keyof RequestTypes[KModel][KMethod]
    ? RequestTypes[KModel][KMethod]["response"]
    : never
> {}
```